# How to create JIRA Kanban based on ticket/card reporter?

Tags: kanban, jira, kanban-board

I want to create another Kanban board in my project where the columns are people names (we have 4 analysts in the team) and in the column shows all the cards created (reported) by each analyst, so we have a quick "go-to" to see who made which cards, and to keep track of our own cards more easily.

I can't seem to find how to map a "status" to "reporter"

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for makes no sense in the context of Kanban. In Kanban, each column is a step in a workflow so that the workflow and the state of work in that workflow can be visualized. However, a reporter is not a state in the workflow.

You can generate swimlanes for each reporter, though. Unfortunately, you can't do this dynamically. You would need to create queries that return the set of issues that you want in each workflow, which would be one query for each analyst on the team. The more typical breakdown is by the current assignee of the issue, or some other method - there are some built in swimlane formats.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in Jira unless you have some hacked awful workflow where everyone has their own status and each status corresponds to a different column on the board.